# My location is not displayed on the map in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit

When I was using let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((userLocation?.coordinate)!, 600, 600) it was fine, however apparently Swift has now replaced this with

let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (userLocation?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)

My location no longer appears on the map anymore, the map shows the right area. Here is my code.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    let userLocation = locations.last
    let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (userLocation?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)

    self.map.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

first hope you didn't forget to extends your viewcontroller from `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and `MKMapViewDelegate`. 
you can access the userlocation directly from `locationManager` variable `private let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()` from anywhere in your class by calling 
`userLocation = self.locationManager.location`

also don't forget to delegate your view controller to location manager and mapview :

```
locationManager.delegate = self
        mapView.delegate = self
```